# Como fazer uma tabela em um scaffold rails com os atributos de outro scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algoritmo-de-busca, scaffold

pessoal estou com uma dificuldade!
Criei um scaffold chamado livro e um chamado emprestimos 
depois criei um chamado relatorio no relatorio quero fazer uma busca de emprestimos por livros

estou usando a gem ransack para fazer buscas dentro do mesmo scaffold, mas como nesse caso e dentro de outro scaffold nao estou conseguindo

criei o scaffold relatorios asssim:
rails g scaffold relatorio livro:references emprestimo:references

Answer (score 0):

Quando você usa o scaffold ele gera apenas uma parte do código.
Se você quiser dar mais vida ao software é preciso escrever os relacionamentos.

Você precisa abrir as classes Livro, Emprestimo e Relatorio e edita-las, adicionando o relacionamento entre elas.

Você pode usar o **has many through association**

```
# model/livro.rb
class Livro < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relatorios
  has_many :emprestimos, through: :relatorios
end

# model/relatorio.rb 
class Relatorio < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :livro
  belongs_to :emprestimo
end

# model/emprestimo.rb
class Emprestimo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relatorios
  has_many :livros, through: :relatorios
end
```