# Busca dentro de outro scaffold rails

Tags: postgresql, query, ruby-on-rails, view

Estou com um problema, um exemplo criei dois scaffold livro e emprestimo, depois criei um controller e uma index chamada relatorio :

```
rails generate controller RelatoriosEmprestimos index
```

Eu quero fazer buscas especificas do scaffold emprestimos nesse controller que criei.

Estou precisando muito resolver isso desde ja agradeço

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer uma tabela em um scaffold rails com os atributos de outro scaffold](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305208/como-fazer-uma-tabela-em-um-scaffold-rails-com-os-atributos-de-outro-scaffold)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende de como quer buscar.
O básico é:

```
class RelatoriosEmprestimos < ApplicationController

  def index
    @emprestimos = Emprestimo.where(campo1: 'condicao1', campo2: 'condicao2')
  end
end
```

A "busca" em questão é feita pelo modelo no controller. Poderia ser qualquer controller e qualquer método que seria a mesma coisa.

Mas é o básico. Se quer um sistema mais complexo de busca, terá que ver outra opções.